# Single bar stacked chart in DC

Tags: r, html, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I am trying to populate a single column stacked bar chart. It is just a sum of one value stacked over the other i.e. the sum of 'LB' experiments stacked over the 'Random' experiments.

Since I need to give a dimension value to the chart I have assumed a Dim variable with 1 as its value for both lb and random.

I am getting the above described data using the following code:

```
d3.csv("file:///D:/Optus/LARS T&L/Dashboard/html/dummy2.csv",function(error, experiments) {   
var ndx                 = crossfilter(experiments),
rDim        = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.Dim;});

var lb = rDim.group().reduceSum(function(d){return d.LBRandom=="LB"?d.Contacted:0;});
var ran = rDim.group().reduceSum(function(d){return d.LBRandom=="Random"?d.Contacted:0;});
```

Although when I am trying to plot this data, the browser only displays the the axis and no data is plotted:

Code for plotting:

```
chart
.width(768)
.height(480)
.x(d3.scale.ordinal())
.y(d3.scale.linear().domain([0,200000])) 
.brushOn(false)
.dimension(rDim)
.group(lb)
.stack(ran)
.render(); 
 });
```

Can anyone help me out with this? It's my 1st day working with d3, dc & crossfilters libraries.
Thanks!

Comment: `console.log(lb.all())` to make sure you're getting data?

Comment: Yes I was getting the data. But as it turns out, the values were getting plotted the whole time. I wasn't able to distinguish the bar from the Y-Axis as it was a single line completely overlapped by the Y-Axis.

After setting elasticY=True i was able to see the bar. :D

Comment: Nice! Glad you found your chart!